# Merge branch without deleting it in git

Tags: git, git-merge

Can I merge a branch without deleting it?

If I have branch "personal-work-in-progress", and a branch "feature/ABC-123" that is five commits ahead of it, is it possible to merge the five commits from feature/ABC-123 into personal-work-in-progress without deleting the feature/ABC-123 branch?

I know doing five `git cherry-pick` commands would do it, but that seems a bit tedious and error-prone.

Comment: `git merge` does not delete branches. Are you using some other tool, like `gitflow`?

Comment: @jpaugh No wonder I couldn't find what I was looking for in the docs! I usually use gitflow or merging on websites. I hardly ever, if at all, use `git merge` until now.

Comment: Glad I could help! I avoid gitflow for precisely the reason that it confuses me when I don't know exactly what a tool is doing "for" me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this

```
git merge branch_name
```

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge